# why the rust rocket auto lower case the http header

Tags: rust, rocket

when I using this command to requst the rust rocket `rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }` server:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage/app/cruise/channel/v1/page' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8083' \
  -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8083/app/cruise/channel' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'x-access-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'x-request-id: 31e8c0fa-be6b-4d06-9fa5-54549fe79967' \
  -H 'appId: jgjguyyg' \
  -H 'userId: 1' \
  --data-raw '{"current":1,"pageSize":20,"pageNum":1,"editorPick":null,"minimalReputation":0}' \
  --compressed
```

from the server side, I found the rocket auto lowercase the `userId` to `userid`. why the rust rocket change the header key? I did not search any explain about this action.

Comment: The question is more why it should support different spellings. HTTP headers are by definition case insensitive (see [RFC 7230 section 3.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2)). Therefore it makes sense to make access to these header case-insensitive to not wrongly depend on specific spelling. Normalizing these headers to lower case is an easy way to do this and [this is also done by other frameworks](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#method-url-and-headers).

Comment: Also keep in mind that [RFC 7540 Section 8.1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2) for HTTP/2 specifies that `request or response containing uppercase header field names MUST be treated as malformed`. So I wouldn't even send it that way.

Comment: @peterulb That section was updated slightly in RFC 9113; same idea, but more straight-forward statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73356889